# difference between NSmanagedObject and NSmanagedObjectContext and persistent store coordinator with small examples?

Tags: ios, core-data

difference between NSmanagedObject and NSmanagedObjectContext and persistent store coordinator , with some examples please explain ?.

Comment: What is your understanding of what they do? What documentation did you read?

Comment: read the documentation on CoreData

Answer (score 0):

The `NSmanagedObjectContext` as its name points out is the `context` for the `NSmanagedObject`. It stores the fetched object graph so you can modify it freely without touching the stored data itself. It can add or remove objects from the graph.

If you choose to save the changes, the `NSManagedObjectContext` checks the objects validity. If they're valid, the changes are then written to persistent store(s).

**NSManagedObject**:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Foundation

class Person : NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String?

}
```

**The CoreData coordinator class**:

In the store class save the changes ...

```
do {
    try managedObjectContext.save()
} catch {
    fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
}
```